# Redshift: Layered correlated subquery pattern not supported

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a manifest table that has the latest processed timestamp of account/version combinations. I want to filter a raw events table to give me only the newest unprocessed timestamps based on the account/version combinations.

```
-- ERROR: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to
-- internal error
FROM events e
WHERE
    CASE WHEN (e.account_id, e.app_version, e.app_build)
        IN (SELECT DISTINCT account_id, app_version, app_build FROM manifest)
    THEN
        tstamp > (SELECT last_processed_tstamp FROM manifest m
                  WHERE m.account_id = e.account_id
                      AND m.app_version = e.app_version
                      AND m.app_build = e.app_build)
    ELSE
        1=1
    END
```

Oddly too, if I only check one column in the CASE-WHEN, it works

```
-- Somehow this works
FROM events e
WHERE
    CASE WHEN e.account_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM manifest)
    THEN
        tstamp > (SELECT last_processed_tstamp FROM manifest m
                  WHERE m.account_id = e.account_id
                      AND m.app_version = e.app_version
                      AND m.app_build = e.app_build)
    ELSE
        1=1
    END
```

Unfortunately though this is the wrong logic since it isn't filtering by the correct account/version combination. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OR.

```
CASE WHEN 
(e.account_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT account_id, app_version, app_build FROM 
manifest) 
OR( e.app_version IN (SELECT DISTINCT account_id, app_version, app_build 
FROM manifest) 
OR (e.app_build IN (SELECT DISTINCT account_id, app_version, app_build FROM 
manifest))
THEN ....
```

I'd break out the sub select to make sure you're only running it once.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I need all 3 columns to be matched as a single unit of comparison though, not separately.